Why are items showing up in a 2d array that I didn't add?
I am having a problem with my code.
When I add an element to a 2d array, it adds two instead. Here are some outputs to help explain the problem:
Blank game board:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Adding to board: 7, 0
After adding first piece:

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 
7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Found a 7 at: 6, 7
Found a 7 at: 7, 0

I initialize a 2d array (I've tried locally and globally) with every element being 0. Then I add a game piece to the board.
Here is my full code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


// 2D array representing the board
int gameBoard[7][7];

// Translates chess code to array index
int translate(char letter){

  if ( letter == 'a' || letter == '8' ){
    return 0;
  } else if ( letter == 'b' || letter == '7' ){
    return 1;
  } else if ( letter == 'c' || letter == '6' ){
    return 2;
  } else if ( letter == 'd' || letter == '5' ){
    return 3;
  } else if ( letter == 'e' || letter == '4' ){
    return 4;
  } else if ( letter == 'f' || letter == '3' ){
    return 5;
  } else if ( letter == 'g' || letter == '2' ){
    return 6;
  } else if ( letter == 'h' || letter == '1' ){
    return 7;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }

}

// Displays current game board
void showBoard(){

  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
      cout << gameBoard[i][j] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

// Initiates game board
void initBoard(){

  for (int i=0; i <= 7; i++){
    for (int j=0; j <= 7; j++){

      gameBoard[i][j] = 0;

    }
  }

}

// Adds a piece to the board
void addPiece(string square){

  int x = translate(square[1]);
  int y = translate(square[0]);

  cout << "Adding to board: " << x << ", " << y << endl;
  gameBoard[x][y] = 7;

}

int main() {

  // Initialize game board with zeros
  initBoard();

  // Display 2d array (game board)
  cout << "Blank game board:\n\n";
  showBoard();

  // Place first piece on board
  string firstPiece = "a1";
  addPiece(firstPiece);

  // Display 2d array (game board)
  cout << "After adding first piece:\n\n";
  showBoard();


  for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++){

      if (gameBoard[i][j] == 7){

        cout << "Found a 7 at: " << i << ", " << j << endl;

      }

    }

  }


}




I can confirm that that "translation" portion is functioning correctly. All that's going on here is translating a1 to 7 and 0 for row and column coordinates.
As you can see, even the program execution agrees that only 1 item is being added to the board. So why do I keep finding two? Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!
I have tried declaring the array (GameBoard) in many different ways and it still adds two when I add only one element. I only want one element to be added to the GameBoard.
This problem doesn't appear for every square I decide to add a piece to. Valid squares are chess board related so a1-h8.

there are 7 elements in a 7 element array, but your loops for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++) { have 8 iterations. The last valid index in a 7 element array is 6 not 7

int gameBoard[7][7]; and for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++). The sizes don't match. A chess board is 8x8 which means it should be declared as int gameBoard[8][8] and you usually write your for loops condition with a less than, not a less or equal than which would look like this: for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++). With your current code you access elements which do not exist because the 2d-array is not big enough. This means that your program has undefined behavior (UB).

or even better use std::array and range based for loops

On a side note: your translate() function can be simplified into just 2 ifs, eg: int translate(char letter){ if ( letter >= 'a' && letter <= 'h' ) { return letter - 'a'; } else if ( letter >= '1' && letter <= '8' ) { return 8 - (letter - '0'); } else { return -1; } }

When you declare an array with int array[7], the length of the array is 7, so the max index is 6.
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
//       index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

When you use any index greater than the max index (or less than zero), you are accessing memory that is not yours, this can cause issues such as a crash if this memory contains your code.
To fix this problem, initialize game board with the correct length. A chess board is 8x8, so you would change the line int gameBoard[7][7]; to now read int gameBoard[8][8];. In my testing, this fixed the problem.
